# How can I find a range in an array using user input?

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

```
package assignment;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class assignment {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] a = new double[] {9.0, 8.0, 7.0, 6.0, 5.0, 4.0};

        int index1;
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("index 1 invoeren");
        index1 = user_input.nextInt();

        int index2;
        System.out.println("index 2 invoeren");
        index2 = user_input.nextInt();

        //System.out.println(index1);
        //System.out.println(index2);


    }

    public void DoubleSegsum(double[] a, int from, int to){

    }

}
```

I need to write a method DoubleSegsum (as seen last) where I can get the sum of the elements of `a`, between position `from` and `to`.
For example (a, 2, 4) should return 13. 
I was trying something with

```
Arrays.asList(a).indexOf(index1)
```

but that will give me `-1` every time
And I don't know how to make it wors in the other method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public double DoubleSegsum(double[] a, int from, int to){
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = from; i < to && i < a.length; i++) {
        sum += a[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, I'm a beginner as u can see. Don't really know how everything works, so thank you for your help and tips

Comment: @LiekeJanssen If I helped you, you should upvote this answer and mark as corrected by mark check, to close the question. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void DoubleSegsum(double[] a, int from, int to){

            double sum=0;
            for(int i=from;i<to;i++){
                sum+=a[i];
            }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using simple `for` loop, use start and stop like:

```
double sum=0;
for(int i=start; i<stop; i++)
sum+=array[i];
```

Comment: Good answer but please don't enable sloppy posts like this question.

Comment: Plus what if stop is > length or start is < 0?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
public void DoubleSegsum(double[] a, int from, int to){
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(;from < to; from++){
      sum += a[from];
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public double doubleSegsum(double[] a, int from, int to) {
    return DoubleStream.of(a).skip(from).limit(to-from).sum();
}
```